# How can an Eleventy site display a list of pages in a directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, static-site

I’m setting up a new [Eleventy](https://www.11ty.io) site, and I’ve run into one slight roadblock. My pages are organized into subdirectories. I want the index page of each directory to list all of the pages in that directory.

For example:

```
|--section1
|  |--index.njk // this should list /section1/page1/, /section2/page2/, etc.
|  |--page1.md
|  |--page2.md
|   --(etc...)
|--section2
|  |--index.njk // this should list /section2/page1/, etc.
|  |--page1.md
|   --(etc..)
```

It looks like Eleventy provides functionality similar to this with its [collections](https://www.11ty.io/docs/collections/) feature. However, it seems like collections only uses data provided in tags.

I can get the output that I want by specifying `tags: ["section1"]` in the front matter of each `page.md`. However, that means more redundant metadata to maintain.

It also looks like I might be able to generate the collections I need using a `eleventyConfig.addCollection` function that would sort through `collections.all()` and return ones based on their `outputPath`. But that feels very hacky to me, and I’m wondering if there’s a more elegant solution.

Ideally, I’d like to be able to put something like this in my `index.njk` template:

```
{%- for page in directory -%}
{# do stuff #}
{%- endfor -%}
```

or perhaps

```
{%- for page in collections.directory -%}
{# do stuff #}
{%- endfor -%}
```

Is there something I’m missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out.

You can add a [data file to each directory](https://www.11ty.io/docs/data-template-dir/) and add the directory name as a tag.

For example, `section1/section1.json` would contain:

```
{
    "tags": ["Section 1"]
}
```

That will be applied to all of the pages in that directory. *However*, any tags specified in the individual pages will override it. You have to enable the [data deep merge](https://www.11ty.io/docs/config/#data-deep-merge) feature to merge directory and page tags. Just add `eleventyConfig.setDataDeepMerge(true);` to your `.eleventy.js` config file.

The documentation states that this feature will be enabled by default in future versions. As of this writing, it’s still opt-in only.